# How to pass argument to a ex command after chaining it with <bar>?

Tags: command-line, ex-command

I'm trying to make my life easier with vim fugitive and ex command line, by creating an abbreviation to a frequent task, which is switching to develop, pulling it and creating new branch.

That's my abbreviation:

```
cab gcdp G checkout develop <bar> :G pull <bar> :G checkout -b
```

I was hoping that it will stop execution after last command and allow me to input name of the branch. Apparently it is not default behaviour. Vim will execute every command without stopping and I will get `error: switch -b requires a value`

I went trough [ex command line dosc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html) but could not find anything that would help me.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted a normal-mode mapping rather than a command-line abbreviation? Or just a custom command?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your question; if I use your abbreviation then it will fill the commandline with that you've written if I type `gcdp`, and I can type the branch name. What do you mean with "hoping that it will stop execution after last command"?

Comment: @MartinTournoij in that case your behaviour differs to mine. In my case all three commands are executed. There is no chance to input branch name. Last command acts like if there was a `<cr>` at the end of it.

Comment: Do you press enter or space after typing `:gcdp`?

Comment: I always press `space`, but with this one I was pressing `enter`. Really do not know why :). Good catch @D.BenKnoble, thanks for the help, mate.

Comment: @LukaszBielsko feel free to add your answer if you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was pressing `enter`, which was executing the last command without letting me input branch name.

`space` should have been pressed instead.